# stripslashes stripes protocol from POST

Tags: php, stripslashes

I've a simple php code were I like to get rid of slashes from a POST from a textarea with [`striplashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
$x = '<img src=\"https://www.domain.tld/img.jpg\">';

echo 'X1: '.$x;

$x = stripslashes($x);

echo 'X2 : '.$x;
```

The output is

```
X1: <img src=\"https://www.domain.tld/img.jpg\">;
X2: <img src="//www.domain.tld/img.jpg">;
```

Why is the **protocol** (http) removed? This happens only on some servers so is it maybe a server "issue"

**addition:**

If I change `$x` to

```
$x = 'img src=\"https://www.domain.tld/img.jpg\"';
```

it works (without brackets)

Comment: `stripslashes` wouldn't do that. I'd look elsewhere in the code for some sort of post-processing. Chances are someone put in code to remove the protocol so hard-coded `http://` images would work on a `https://` site. Incidentally, needing `stripslashes` at all is often a code-smell. Why is the textarea escaped like that?

Comment: You probably have magic_quotes enabled. A modern PHP install wouldn't automatically escape quotes from form data...

Comment: There's a bunch of HTML in a textarea and gets sent via POST to the script. It's part of a WordPress plugin. But why is `X1` right but not `X2`. It seems `stripslashes` does it

Comment: @MarcB how to test this, and what should I do? should I just remove `stripslashes`?

Comment: it'd be a php.ini option. magic_quotes should never be on anymore. it was a moronically stupid thing to start with, and has properly been killed/removed from php.

Comment: Sorry, guys! The issue was because of an external JS which was executed after the page was loaded. The problem why it was showing that way after `stripslashes` is a mysteries though. Please vote for close!